# XAML - not just hide but *remove* element via binding

Tags: .net, wpf, performance, xaml

I have a list of viewmodels which have a boolean ShowIcon property. In the UI I'm planning to use a template binding that will hide or show an icon on each row, using this property.

However, there could be quite a few items in the list, so rather than just setting `Visibility` on the icon, bound to the `ShowIcon` property (probably using a `ValueConverter` to convert `bool` to `Visibility.Hidden`) I'd like those row to actually have *nothing* where the icon would be.

That is to say it's a performance enhancement that I'm not even sure I'll need yet, but I suspect I will, so am asking the question in the hope of having the right answer if I find the UI is sluggish because of the sheer number of visual elements (or do I mean logical?) in the tree, even when they're hidden.

Comment: You may set `Visibility.Collapsed` instead of `Hidden`, so that the invisible element does not participate in layout. It won't get into the visual tree, and will not impact performance. Otherwise this would just be a case of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization), imo.

Comment: Yes as I pointed out in my question I know it's premature optimisation (in the hope of avoiding exactly that kind of response). However, given there could be scenarios where perf becomes a problem (regardless of whether mine has yet or not) I wanted to learn more about XAML and how to tackle such an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Have you thought about using 2 different templates (one with and the other without image) and a DataTemplateSelector?

Comment: I have not enough reputation to add a comment to that question

Comment: Yes I have actually just discovered that avenue. I think that's probably exactly what I want.